# JavaScript Patterns: Context of Function Call

Tags: javascript, function, call

I have a ton of JavaScript from the dawn of time with function calls written like this:

```
THING.someFunction.call(THING);
```

It seems to me that should always be equivalent to:

```
THING.someFunction();
```

**Are these two calls always equivalent?** What about old versions of JavaScript?

It seems to me the purpose of the second `THING` in that first line of code is to set the context (`this`) inside `someFunction`. But the context inside that function should already be `THING` by default, right?

Just to be clear, `THING` is defined something like this:

```
var THING = function () {
    // private vars

    return{
        // code
        someFunction : function () {
            // code
        }
    };
}();
```

Comment: The way you have your code now, `THING.someFunction` is `undefined`.

Comment: I believe you are missing parentheses at the end of THING declaration ie. THING = function{ }();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are equivalent. And I don't know any version of JavaScript in which they were not (however, [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) seems to have been added in 1.3).

Comment: I finally realized that I could test the truth of my hypothesis using Firebug. You are correct. And since you answered first, I'll hand the win to you. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same technically. But they also behave slightly different in asynchronous programming. call() is used to call a function by passing a scope as the parameter. This provides a convenient way to call defined functions in callbacks and delayed execution (setTimeout, setInterval). If you have used any of the JS libraries, you would have noticed $.proxy, or _.bind, these are aliases that implement call(scope);

See [this MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) for more info.

Comment: Why the downvote? Can you please point out what was incorrect in what I stated? I'd like to correct myself if I understood something wrong at the very least.

Comment: Did you read the MDN doc in my answer? The first argument in call() is 'thisArg' which can be set to any object that represents scope (context).

Comment: Did _you_ read that MDN page? It doesn't use the word 'scope' at all. The value of 'this' is not at all the same thing as a function's scope. Scope is about which variables and functions can be accessed from a particular block, e.g., a nested function can of course access its own local variables, but it can also access (non-shadowed) variables up through the scope chain, and globals.

Comment: Yes, I did read the that article which is why I put it there. What does 'this' keyword represent, if not scope? When you pass an object of your own instead of this, null, undefined to call(), doesn't the function execute in the context of the object you passed? I know I am using the words scope/context interchangeably, is that wrong?

Comment: 'Scope' is the wrong word for what you are describing. In general terms scope is about which variables a function has access to - think about nested functions, where an inner function can access variables declared in the outer function (simple in some languages, but more confusing in JS with closures). Using .call() or .apply() only sets 'this', not the scope.